# Cannot place the Latlong at the center of map on popup

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I tried alot to place the latlong at the center of the map on popup but still unable to  place it at center.here is my code and latlong is coming dynamically from database.

```
<script>
   var amsterdam = new google.maps.LatLng("<?php echo $lats; ?>","<?php echo $lons;?>");

function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:amsterdam,
  zoom:8,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
var myCity = new google.maps.Circle({
  center:amsterdam,
  radius:<?php echo $rad;?>,
  strokeColor:"#0000FF",
  strokeOpacity:0.8,
  strokeWeight:2,
  fillColor:"#0000FF",
  fillOpacity:0.4
  });
var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:amsterdam,
  animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
  });

marker.setMap(map);
myCity.setMap(map);
//google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
  } google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:340px;margin-left: 4px;margin-top: 15px;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't wrap the coordinates with `"` because they will be treated as strings. Try without the double inverted commas. If all fail, use `parseFloat()` on the echoed latitude and longitude.

Comment: yes...its working i got my answer..finally google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); instead of this i change the load parameter to click...

Comment: I'm glad it helped - and if you find it helpful, do accept it as an answer ;)